# Slow wifi internet connection - Mac Mini only - do I need a wifi range extender?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, wireless-router, mac-mini

I have a NetGear DG834B modem router with an ADSL connection on the ground floor. On the 1st floor, I have acceptable connections from my Windows desktop PC, Macbook Pro, iPhone and iPad. However, the Mac Mini (intel core 2 duo), which serves as media centre, has constant speed problems -- endlessly buffering or sometimes failing to play internet video. (Although it never fails to connect to the wireless signal.)

All my computers report different speeds using http://www.speedtest.net. The router reports a downstream connection speed of 18461 kbps, but on the various computers using speedtest.net I get from a maximum of around 10Mbps (PC) down to under 2Mbps (Mac Mini).

Does the Mac Mini just have a weak antenna? Would the problem be cured by something like this? http://www.amazon.co.uk/Netgear-Universal-WiFi-Range-Extender/dp/B003LAD8BY

Or perhaps upgrading the router to an 802-11n device?

*Duplicate problem here, but none of the advice there worked for me:
[Mac Mini’s Internet connection is very slow, every other device’s connection is fine. (PC, iPhone, Xbox 360)](https://superuser.com/questions/139789/mac-minis-internet-very-slow-every-other-device-fine-pc-iphone-xbox-360)*

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it it's likely to be a weak signal problem due to the Mac Mini's low antenna strength. Have you tried moving it downstairs closer to the router to see if it changes?

I'm not sure if there is such a thing as an external antenna for the Mac Mini, your best bet is probably some sort of [wireless repeater](http://www.wirelessrepeaterhq.com). I'd recommend setting up the [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) firmware on it but it looks like it's incompatible with your device.